# CodeIgniter authentication concept issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

I've made CI authentication controller allowing user to log into the site, and after the login I'm redirecting him to the previously visited URL that I keep using:

```
$this->session->set_flashdata( 'return_url', current_url() );
```

Unfortunately that causes a problem. Every time when the user opens more than one tab in the browser that variable is being overwritten and after successful login the user is redirected to the same URL in all the tabs.

So my question is: **Is it possible to load a custom controller inside MY_Controller?** (`MY_Controller` is the class that `extends CI_Controller`)

I tried using (inside the constructor of `MY_Controller`) but it didn't worked out:

```
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->router->set_class('authentication');
$CI->router->set_method('login');
```

Edit: I will appreciate any other ideas of solving this problem.

Comment: No, in CI you can't call a controller with another one.

Comment: Why not using an auto-loaded model for authentication ? I wrote my authentication system as a model and autoloading it, and never had an issue yet. I'm even defining definitions in construct method, which even makes my code tidier + easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a solution would be not to save the return url in a session var, but pass it around in a get/post parameter (in case of get, properly encoded, base64 ie.). The only addition would have to be a standard return url if no (valid) return url is set

--- EDIT
why was i talking about base64 when php has just the function for this; urlencode is your friend! https://www.php.net/urlencode

Comment: `base64`'s hash contains slashes and it messes up with codeigniter's url

Comment: I've managed to avoid this slash problem by replacing all the slashes with an exclamation mark in the hash after encoding and reversing them before decoding the string.

Answer (score 0):

To load a custom controller inside a controller (such as MY_Controller) use php CURL to get to the authentication controller.

This may effect performance as this is an expensive process on every request.

Other options can include using a base class system (see http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/02/CodeIgniter-Base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY) or creating an auto-loaded library to take care of the authentication.

Answer (score 0):

When you're redirecting non-logged in users to login page, keep a hidden variable "redirect_to" which will hold value from where the user has arrived. $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER'] can be used. Then after login, simply redirect to the value of "redirect_to". This way you don't have to set flashdata to redirect users from the url they came.

Comment: It's `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` and cannot be used when you have redirected the user with php header